# jsp/servlet dynamically create pages

Tags: jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

I'm developing classified website using jsp/servlet and MVC architecture. Majority of work have done now. But I have a problem now. When users submit ads those ads should display in web page. That page can contain only  10 ads,means 11th ad should go to 2nd page. Is it possible to do this with  JSP.
(I'm glad if You guys can explain with good examples)
Thank you.
Dilshan.

Comment: No one gonna help me with this?

Comment: are you going to post any code?  Of course it can be done with JSP since Java is Turing-complete.

Comment: I have no idea where to start that part..
give me some ideas about it..

Comment: A quick google gave tons of quality results : https://www.google.co.in/search?q=paging+application+in+jsp&oq=paging+application+in+jsp&aqs=chrome..69i57.4597j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=pagination+application+in+jsp&safe=off

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. coding_idiot. This is what i looked for whole day along with out knowing keyword (pagination).
Thank You Very much again.
Dilshan.